# Binomial representation

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

We already know that we can represent this binomial as the following:

$$(a+b)^K=\sum _{n=0}^K \binom{K}{n} b^n a^{K-n};$$

where $\binom{K}{n} = \frac{K!}{n! (K-n)!}$

I want to know if this representation is correct for the reciprocal binomial expression:

$$\frac{1}{(a+b)^K}=\sum _{n=0}^K \frac{1}{\binom{K}{n} b^n a^{K-n}};$$

where $K$ is a positive integer larger than zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $|a|>|b|$ then

$$
\begin{align}
& \frac{1}{(a+b)^K} \\[8pt]
= {} & (a+b)^{-K} = a^{-K} + (-K)a^{-K-1}b + \frac{-K(-K-1)}{2} a^{-K-1}b^2 \\[8pt]
& {} + \frac{-K(-K-1)(-K-2)}{6} a^{-K-3} b^3 + \cdots \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-K}{n} a^{-K-n} b^n.
\end{align}
$$

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem

Comment: could you please write the compact summation form represetation?

Comment: 1- If a and b are real numbers greater than zero, the above statement is the same, I mean can we omit the condition of $|a|>|b|$ because there is + sign between them?
2- Why the upper limit of the summation is $\infty$, (i.e. why it is not K), bearing in mind K is positive integer greater than zero ?

Comment: @barznjy : If the exponent were $4$, so that the coefficients were $1,4,6,4,1$, then we could write $\dfrac{4\cdot3}{2!}$, $\dfrac{4\cdot3\cdot2}{3!}$, $\dfrac{4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}{4!}$, $\dfrac{4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot0}{5!}$, $\dfrac{4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot0\cdot(-1)}{6!}$, and so on, and we'd have an infinite sequence in which everything after the fifth term is zero.  But when the exponent is either negative or a non-integer, then we never get zero.  The condition $|a|>|b|$ assures us that the series converges.

Comment: 1- Is it (1,-4,6,-4,1) or (1,4,6,4,1)?
2- So we can say that totally we have (K+1) terms, (and for our specific case when K is integer, we can say the upper limit of the summation is (K+1)); is that correct?

Comment: @barznjy : I was speaking of the coefficients when the exponent is $4$.  Those are $1,4,6,4,1$.  And one can view them as $1,4,6,4,1,0,0,0,\ldots$.

Comment: What about the the coefficients when the exponent is $-4$?
( i.e. $(a+b)^{-4}$ ).

Comment: Then you have $1,-4,\dfrac{(-4)(-5)}{2!},\dfrac{(-4)(-5)(-6)}{3!},\dfrac{(-4)(-5)(-6)(-7)}{4!},\ldots$.

Comment: Could you tell me a reference book that mentioned this equation:
$ (a+b)^{-K} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-K}{n} a^{-K-n} b^n $

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely **not**.  What you wrote is equivalent to claiming that $$\frac{1}{a+b} = \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}.$$